# CartoDB Visualize Button

Tags: carto

For some reason I can't ever see the "Visualize" button. It flashes briefly and then switches to "Publish". This happens regardless of browser. I've updated everything and it still happens. I'm running Windows 8.1 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a dataset or a map? That button will show:

- Visualize if you are on dataset and it will create a map from it
- Publish if you are no a map and will show the sharing options

Comment: That seems to be the difference. It was confusing because the "Visualize" would flash then disappear on the map view and documentation made it seem like it should persist.. I suppose that's a quirk (bug?) in the UX.

Comment: Yeah, it's because the UI is reused and labels are placed a bit later than they should be :-)